# how to sent-RdsUserSessionMessage to users who is using the sessionhost?

Tags: windows, azure, powershell, azure-powershell, vdi

I want to send message to the users. I found the [Send-RdsUserSessionMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/windowsvirtualdesktop/send-rdsusersessionmessage).

1. I want to send message to all users who is using the special
   SessionHostName.
2. Is it possible to send message to assigned session host of one host pool?

And the samples are as below:

**Example 1: Send a message to a user session by providing all required information**

```
PS C:\> Send-RdsUserSessionMessage -TenantName "contoso" -HostPoolName "contosoHostPool" -SessionHostName "sh1.contoso.com" -SessionId 1 -MessageTitle "Test announcement" -MessageBody "Test message."
```

**Example 2: Send a message to a user by searching for their user session**

```
PS C:\> Get-RdsUserSession -TenantName "contoso" -HostPoolName "contosoHostPool" | where { $_.UserPrincipalName -eq "contoso\user1" } | Send-RdsUserSessionMessage -MessageTitle "Test announcement" -MessageBody "Test message." -NoUserPrompt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding #1, based on description section in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/windowsvirtualdesktop/get-rdsusersession#description) document I believe you can lists all user sessions running on the session hosts in the specified host pool using  [Get-RdsUserSession](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/windowsvirtualdesktop/get-rdsusersession) cmdlet and then pipeline with [Send-RdsUserSessionMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/windowsvirtualdesktop/send-rdsusersessionmessage) cmdlet to send message to all those user sessions

Regarding #2, based on example 1 in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/windowsvirtualdesktop/get-rdssessionhost#examples) document and description section in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/windowsvirtualdesktop/new-rdshostpool#description) document I believe it is possible to assign different session host names of one host pool

Hope this information helps!

Comment: Thanks for your comments. But I cannot understand **Refarding #2** very well. For example: there has a host pool with three session host VMs (vm1, vm2, vm3), I want to sent message who is log in vm2 and vm3, how to achieve the goal with one runbook?